# Update a MongoDB document in JAVA without explicit conversion

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am using the mongo-db java driver 3.8 and work with the collection as follows:

```
MongoDatabase md=mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName);
MongoCollection<ConstructionPlan> collection=md.getCollection(plansCollectionName,abc.class);
collection.insertOne(item);
collection.find(Filters.eq("itemId", id),abc.class).first();
```

With this code I do not have to do any conversion. I was looking for a way to update an document the same way. I am thinking on something like this:

```
abc anABCObject=collection.find(Filters.eq("itemId", id),ConstructionPlan.class).first();
//updates...
collection.update(anABCObject);
```

Is there a way to update an existing document without BSON conversion? (I was unable to find it....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`updateOne` for updating document fields using update operators.

You need `replaceOne` which takes the replacement document.

```
collection.replaceOne(
   Filters.eq("itemId", id),
   anABCObject
);
```